# None of my HTML is showing up on my PHP page

Tags: php, html

I have 3 files (these are the only three that matter): footer.php, header.php, and index.php. In index.php I have some php that says `require header.php` and `require footer.php`. All my HTML is correct I believe, no errors. I will show one example of where everything it going wrong. I'm using an XAMPP server on my mac, and I have this HTML in the php file header.php:

```
<a href="#">
    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
</a>
```

However, when I use inspect element on my php page, this is what shows up:

```
<header>
        <nav>
            <a href="#">

            </a>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Keep in mind that there is a lot more code that should be in those header tags, but that is all that shows up. In inspect, it shows up as a 0 by 1024 or something like that element. What are my issues with the header?

For reference, here is my header.php file:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
            </a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div>

                <form action="includes/login.inc.php" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="mailuid" placeholder="Username/Email...">
                    <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password...">
                    <button type="submit" name="login-submit">Login</button>
                </form>

                <a href="signup.php">Signup</a>

                <form action="includes/logout.inc.php" method="post">
                    <button type="submit" name="logout-submit">Logout</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Here is the index.php code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test I guess</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        require "header.php";
    ?>

        <main>
            <p>You are logged out!</p>

            <p>You are logged in!</p>
        </main>

    <?php
        require "footer.php"
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Nothing at all is showing up HTML-wise, not even the title.

Comment: Your header.php contains a whole page, including `<html>` tags. Shouldn't it be partial and contains only `<header>` tag and content ?

Comment: Try View Source, not Inspect Element, to see what PHP is outputting.

Comment: also please show us the index.php code

Comment: @Cid I removed everything but `<header>` tag and that changed nothing.

Comment: @Moayad.AlMoghrabi done

Comment: @jso_8910, I just tested the code at my end, and everything works just fine. try checking your apache to see if it is running correctly.

Comment: @Moayad.AlMoghrabi everything is working, because, when I only have a file called index.php on another project, everything runs well. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Okay @jso_8910, then I suggest you follow as told in the answers and tell us if this is working.

Comment: @Moayad.AlMoghrabi check my comment on the top answer by ADyson

Answer (score 1):

You've got two separate HTML documents there, one in header.php and one in index.php. You're then including one inside the other. This will not make sense to the browser and is likely the main cause of your problem.

The browser expects to work with one single coherent HTML document. Therefore each final output to the browser (generated by the combination of PHP scripts) must contain only one `<html>` tag, one one `<head>` tag and one `<body>` tag.

This would make more sense:

**header.php**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Your site name</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
            </a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div>

                <form action="includes/login.inc.php" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="mailuid" placeholder="Username/Email...">
                    <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password...">
                    <button type="submit" name="login-submit">Login</button>
                </form>

                <a href="signup.php">Signup</a>

                <form action="includes/logout.inc.php" method="post">
                    <button type="submit" name="logout-submit">Logout</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
    require "header.php";
?>

    <main>
        <p>You are logged out!</p>

        <p>You are logged in!</p>
    </main>

<?php
    require "footer.php"
?>
```

**footer.php**

```
</body>
</html>
```

Then there's only one HTML document being output, there's no unnecessary repetition of markup which is needed on all the pages, but also the HTML document remains open for the individual pages to add body content.

Comment: For some reason, this code is still not working. I'm thinking at this point that the issue may be something with the HTML not updating somehow (I have no idea) because there was a point where my code looked like the code that the page is outputting. I really have no idea what is going on. For reference, I used the exact code that you used (plus an opening and closing `<footer>` tag in footer.php), and the source code in view source code didn't change at all.

Comment: Can you define more precisely what "not working" means now you've made these changes. What actual output do you see in the browser's View Source now? Do you have any errors in your PHP error log (assuming you've set that up, which you should). (And have you done a Ctrl+F5 in your browser to ensure it refreshes the page from the webserver and doesn't try to used a cached copy?)

Comment: By not working I mean that when I right click and press view source code, the code hasn't changed. I am in a Chrome based browser now, and I just tried Safari, and nothing has changed. I really don't understand what's going on.

Comment: maybe you're not updating the right file on the server. Try adding some logging in the PHP code to write a file to the disk when it runs. Then you'd hopefully know for certain if it's executing the file you think it is. Also check for any errors in the PHP logs (which hopefully you've already configured). Or try creating a whole new PHP file using this new code, and try running that from your browser instead.

Comment: I'm sorry for wasting your time. I started checking where all the files were, and after a minute or so, I realized there were two copies of the files: one on my Desktop, and one in  the HTDocs folder.

Comment: It happens. Not to worry. Consider it a lesson learned in double-checking what you're doing! And don't keep multiple copies of your files lying around - instead use source control to store a history of your changes etc. But you still had a logical problem in your original code, and this code in my answer will still help you overcome that. So it was still a useful exercise overall.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following things.

1. make sure apache server(xampp, lamp, wamp, mamp) is running correctly
2. update your header file as below. you dont need  tags in a partial file.
3. make sure header file is in same location as index.php, if it is inside a folder, mention the folder name when using require or include.
4. put the code snippet in top of index.php so you get error messages.

   `<?php
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ?>`

   if the issue is still there, i will need more info. Below is how the header file should look

   ```
   <header>
         <nav>
         <a href="#">
           <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
       </a>
       <ul>
       <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
       </ul>
       <div>

           <form action="includes/login.inc.php" method="post">
               <input type="text" name="mailuid" placeholder="Username/Email...">
               <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password...">
               <button type="submit" name="login-submit">Login</button>
           </form>

           <a href="signup.php">Signup</a>

           <form action="includes/logout.inc.php" method="post">
               <button type="submit" name="logout-submit">Logout</button>
           </form>
       </div>
   </nav>
   ```

Comment: Yeah, thats pretty solid advise. OP should consider this as well.

Comment: actually my point was to encourage you to update your answer to reflect it. But I've added my own more comprehensive answer as well now with the full solution.